# Betting rounds in heads-up Texas holdem?

Tags: betting-position

I know that how betting works. Preflop, player on left of dealer pays SB and on his left BB, and on left of BB starts betting. And after flop, Player on left of dealer starts first.

But if only two players are playing, suppose Ballin and Danny. Assume danny has the Dealer card so ballin is on left of danny so Ballin pays SB and thus danny pays BB and Ballin should start betting preflop.

But I saw a video of Pokerstars.. see the image

[image]

Here Danny pays SB and starts betting preflop. And after flop Ballin starts betting first.

Can someone explain this?

Comment: Not much to explain, your right. Think of the Dealer button as the "Absolute Position on Flop and Later Streets Button." Only in draw poker will the dealer button act last every time action is on them. And even then I've seen draw games played with blinds...

Answer (score 2):

The one with the dealer button always acts last in post-flop play and the big blind is last in pre-flop play. Therefore, since in heads-up the small blind had the dealer button, Danny acts first pre-flop and last post-flop.

This is one of the reasons heads-up is verry different from multiplayer matches.